# Force ExpansionPanel to be expanded, when printing

Tags: reactjs, printing, material-ui

I am using an [ExpansionPanel](https://material-ui.com/api/expansion-panel/#expansionpanel-api),
where I control the `expanded` state based on some conditions.

Although, I want the ExpansionPanel to be always `expanded`, when I am printing (`window.print()`).

What I intuitively wanted to try was:

```
//...

const isPrinting = useMediaQuery("print")
const controlledExpanded = useSomeMethodToControlExpanded()
const expanded = isPrinting || controlledExpanded
return (
  <ExpansionPanel expanded={expanded}>
    {/*...*/}
  </ExpansionPanel>
)
```

Although this won't work because of a [bug in browsers](https://material-ui.com/components/use-media-query/#simple-media-query):

Maybe somehow override the global styling would help, but I cannot figure out how.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@media print` in your css:

```
@media print { 
    div.MuiCollapse-container.MuiCollapse-hidden {
        min-height: auto !important;
        height: auto !important;
        visibility: visible !important;
    }
}
```

No need for anything in the react component